# Does Class-Path on Manifest need to specifically state the directory location of my class?

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have a .jar file that I've compiled and the class is inside many folders levels.

For instance, my class is on: mainFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/MyClass.class 
while my Manifest.mf file contains the "Class-Path: ." .

In my understanding the "." means that my class-path is in the source.

Do we need to specify in class-path that the class is actually on mainFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/MyClass.class instead of only using the "." ?

Comment: Where is your manifest file located relative to your class file and what part of the path is actually also part of the package (e.g. Folder1.Folder2.Folder3.MyClass)?

Comment: @hotzst mainFolder/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. All the folders up to the class are part of the package mainFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/MyClass.class.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your jar file should look like this:

```
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/MyClass.class
/com/stackoverflow/example/MyOtherClass.class
/some.properties
```

Then your do not need to specify any additional entries in the Manifest file. However be sure that the root of the of the jar file is the root of the classes, meaning that in the above case you have the following two classes included:

```
Folder1.Folder2.Folder3.MyClass
com.stackoverflow.example.MyOtherClass
```

For a detailed explanation on the Manifest file take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) of Oracle.